# Error Home page is opened without login using mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

When i run my project it goes to login page working fine

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Account", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
```

When i entered username and password is login properly

```
//[Authorize]
    //[InitializeSimpleMembership]
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Account/
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

#region Login
        [HttpGet]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        public ActionResult Login()
        {
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Login(Login login)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                bool success = WebSecurity.Login(login.UserName, login.Password, false);
                var UserID = GetUserID_By_UserName(login.UserName);

                if (success == true)
                {
                    Session["Name"] = login.UserName;
                    Session["UserID"] = UserID;
                    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
                }
                else
                {
                    ModelState.AddModelError("Error", "Please enter valid Username and Password");
                    return View(login);
                }

            }
            return View(login);
        }
        #endregion

}
```

[image: Login]

once i logout and clear the session and When i entered URL bar `localhost:51426/Home/index` to the home page that home page opened directly without login.So home page should n't open without login process.

[image: Empty]

Comment: are u using custom Authorize filter or built in filter

Comment: Authorize filter @Saineshwar

Comment: is it working properly after applying

Comment: Yes it's working good @Saineshwar bellow Nitesh answer is correct it's working fine for me thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the Index method so that Anonymous user can not able to access the page by adding Authorize attribute.

```
// GET: /Account/
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Index()
{
   return View();
}
```